# Image Slider works fine in Chrome but not in IE11

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, sharepoint, internet-explorer-11

Here is a link to my code http://jsfiddle.net/wf32jbhx/

I have tried hosting the images on my sharepoint site as well and the images just stack on top of one another and don't format properly. IT works fine in Chrome on my sharePoint site however.

When I open the .html file up from my local storage on my computer, it displays fine in an IE11 tab. The issue occurs when I try to open it up in IE11 with the file coming from my SharePoint site location. Does anyone know what is causing this issue.

HTML

```
<div id="slideshow-wrap">
    <input type="radio" id="button-1" name="controls" checked="checked"/>
    <label for="button-1"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="button-2" name="controls"/>
    <label for="button-2"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="button-3" name="controls"/>
    <label for="button-3"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="button-4" name="controls"/>
    <label for="button-4"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="button-5" name="controls"/>
    <label for="button-5"></label>
    <label for="button-1" class="arrows" id="arrow-1">></label>
    <label for="button-2" class="arrows" id="arrow-2">></label>
    <label for="button-3" class="arrows" id="arrow-3">></label>
    <label for="button-4" class="arrows" id="arrow-4">></label>
    <label for="button-5" class="arrows" id="arrow-5">></label>
    <div id="slideshow-inner">
        <ul>
            <li id="slide1">
                <img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/3/3yiC6Yq.jpg" />
                <div class="description">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="show-description-1"/>
                    <label for="show-description-1" class="show-description-label">I</label>
                    <div class="description-text">
                        <h2>Flower power</h2>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li id="slide2">
                <img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/4/40Ly3VB.jpg" />
                <div class="description">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="show-description-2"/>
                    <label for="show-description-2" class="show-description-label">I</label>
                    <div class="description-text">
                        <h2>Golden sunset</h2>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li id="slide3">
                <img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/0/00kih8g.jpg" />
                <div class="description">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="show-description-3"/>
                    <label for="show-description-3" class="show-description-label">I</label>
                    <div class="description-text">
                        <h2>Flower power again</h2>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li id="slide4">
                <img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/2/2rT2vdx.jpg" />
                <div class="description">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="show-description-4"/>
                    <label for="show-description-4" class="show-description-label">I</label>
                    <div class="description-text">
                        <h2>Stormy coast</h2>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li id="slide5">
                <img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/8/8k3N3EL.jpg" />
                <div class="description">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="show-description-5"/>
                    <label for="show-description-5" class="show-description-label">I</label>
                    <div class="description-text">
                        <h2>Splash!</h2>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
@font-face {
    font-family: Arial;
}

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    background-image: url(https://team.amer.mymetlife.com/teams/Corpsystems/Site%20images/Slideshow%20Folder/F1_light_blue_flag.svg.png);
    background-repeat: repeat;
    height: 500px;
    padding: 1px;
}

h1 { color: white }

#slideshow-wrap {
    display: block;
    height: 320px;
    min-width: 260px;
    max-width: 640px;
    margin: auto;
    border: 12px rgba(255,255,240,1) solid;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    margin-top: 20px;
    position: relative;
}

#slideshow-inner {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

#slideshow-inner>ul {
    list-style: none;
    height: 100%;
    width: 500%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    left: 0px;
    -webkit-transition: left .8s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
    -moz-transition: left .8s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
    -o-transition: left .8s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
    transition: left .8s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
}

#slideshow-inner>ul>li {
    width: 20%;
    height: 320px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

#slideshow-inner>ul>li>img {
    margin: auto;
    height: 100%;
}

#slideshow-wrap input[type=radio] {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    bottom: 15px;
    z-index: 100;
    visibility: hidden;
}

#slideshow-wrap label:not(.arrows):not(.show-description-label) {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    bottom: -45px;
    z-index: 100;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    background-color: rgba(200,200,200,1);
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    -webkit-transition: background-color .2s;
    -moz-transition: background-color .2s;
    -o-transition: background-color .2s;
    transition: background-color .2s;
}

#slideshow-wrap label:not(.arrows):active { bottom: -46px }

#slideshow-wrap input[type=radio]#button-1:checked~label[for=button-1] { background-color: rgba(0,0,0,1) }

#slideshow-wrap input[type=radio]#button-2:checked~label[for=button-2] { background-color: rgba(0,0,0,1) }

#slideshow-wrap input[type=radio]#button-3:checked~label[for=button-3] { background-color: rgba(0,0,0,1) }

#slideshow-wrap input[type=radio]#button-4:checked~label[for=button-4] { background-color: rgba(0,0,0,1) }

#slideshow-wrap input[type=radio]#button-5:checked~label[for=button-5] { background-color: rgba(0,0,0,1) }

#slideshow-wrap label[for=button-1] { margin-left: -36px }

#slideshow-wrap label[for=button-2] { margin-left: -18px }

#slideshow-wrap label[for=button-4] { margin-left: 18px }

#slideshow-wrap label[for=button-5] { margin-left: 36px }

#slideshow-wrap input[type=radio]#button-1:checked~#slideshow-inner>ul { left: 0 }

#slideshow-wrap input[type=radio]#button-2:checked~#slideshow-inner>ul { left: -100% }

#slideshow-wrap input[type=radio]#button-3:checked~#slideshow-inner>ul { left: -200% }

#slideshow-wrap input[type=radio]#button-4:checked~#slideshow-inner>ul { left: -300% }

#slideshow-wrap input[type=radio]#button-5:checked~#slideshow-inner>ul { left: -400% }

label.arrows {
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: rgb(255,255,240);
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -25px;
    display: none;
    opacity: 0.7;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 1000;
    background-color: transparent;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .2s;
    -moz-transition: opacity .2s;
    -o-transition: opacity .2s;
    transition: opacity .2s;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.8);
}

label.arrows:hover { opacity: 1 }

label.arrows:active { margin-top: -23px }

input[type=radio]#button-1:checked~.arrows#arrow-2, input[type=radio]#button-2:checked~.arrows#arrow-3, input[type=radio]#button-3:checked~.arrows#arrow-4, input[type=radio]#button-4:checked~.arrows#arrow-5 {
    right: -55px;
    display: block;
}

input[type=radio]#button-2:checked~.arrows#arrow-1, input[type=radio]#button-3:checked~.arrows#arrow-2, input[type=radio]#button-4:checked~.arrows#arrow-3, input[type=radio]#button-5:checked~.arrows#arrow-4 {
    left: -55px;
    display: block;
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
    -moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
    -ms-transform: scaleX(-1);
    -o-transform: scaleX(-1);
    transform: scaleX(-1);
}

input[type=radio]#button-2:checked~.arrows#arrow-1 { left: -19px }

input[type=radio]#button-3:checked~.arrows#arrow-2 { left: -37px }

input[type=radio]#button-5:checked~.arrows#arrow-4 { left: -73px }

.description {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 260px;
    font-family: Arial;
    z-index: 1000;
}

.description input { visibility: hidden }

.description label {
    font-family: Arial;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,240,1);
    position: relative;
    left: -17px;
    top: 00px;
    width: 40px;
    height: 27px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 7px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .2s;
    -moz-transition: opacity .2s;
    -o-transition: opacity .2s;
    transition: opacity .2s;
    z-index: 5;
    color: rgb(20,20,20);
}

#slideshow-inner>ul>li:hover .description label { opacity: 1 }

.description input[type=checkbox]:checked~label { opacity: 1 }

.description .description-text {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,230,.5);
    padding-left: 45px;
    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    position: relative;
    top: -35px;
    z-index: 4;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .2s;
    -moz-transition: opacity .2s;
    -o-transition: opacity .2s;
    transition: opacity .2s;
    color: rgb(20,20,20);
}

.description input[type=checkbox]:checked~.description-text { opacity: 1 }
```

Comment: Hit F12 and go to the console in IE11, then refresh your page and see if something is 404ing

Comment: It says I'm getting mixed content. I am loading via https but some images I'm asking for are http. However the image it's claiming I'm trying to pull is no longer being used in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What's the problem?**

SharePoint 2010 and 2007 force Internet Explorer to run in compatibility mode in order to get all the correct browser objects to work smoothly (which gives you functionality like viewing a list in datasheet view, or launching a file in Excel instead of downloading it).

Unfortunately, compatibility view is roughly equivalent to Internet Explorer 8 in terms of what HTML and CSS standards are followed.

If you pop open the F12 developer tools and switch your document emulation mode to 8 instead of Edge, I think you'll find that advanced CSS selectors such as `#slideshow-wrap input[type=radio]#button-5:checked~#slideshow-inner>ul` and the `@font-face` rule simply don't work.

Here's a CSS3 reference that shows which browser versions support which CSS3 properties. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_browsersupport.asp

Also check out the CSS selectors reference here, and be aware that IE8 does not support most of the selectors that are tagged as CSS3 (only CSS1 and CSS2): http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors

**How can you fix it?**

You can either get your code to work with older versions of Internet Explorer, or you can update the masterpage(s) used by your SharePoint sites with a meta tag forcing the browser into Edge mode instead of 8.

Note that if you force the browser into Edge mode, while you'll gain the benefits of modern HTML and CSS, you'll lose the benefits of the IE8-specific ActiveX controls, so be aware of how users are interacting with your SharePoint environment before doing anything sweeping.

It is possible to use multiple different masterpages throughout SharePoint, so you could theoretically whip up a custom masterpage just for those cases where you want to use modern HTML/CSS/JavaScript, and still use the IE8-mode-forcing masterpage for pages where users are directly interacting with SharePoint lists and libraries.

Comment: Thank you so much it is rendering my site in ie8 instead of edge, do you know if this is the correct syntax to put it in EDGE mode?

<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />

Unofrtunately I cannot get access to SharePoint designer so I can't edit the master page. Is there any other method that I can use to change this?

Comment: Yes, that's the correct syntax, and that tag would have to go in between the `<head></head>` tags in the page code. Without being able to edit the masterpage, you might be out of luck. You could manually build your own HTML pages from scratch and save them in a document library on SharePoint, but they'll be missing SharePoint navigation and functionality. Maybe you can use a page viewer web part to display your custom page embedded on a SharePoint page, but I'm not certain if that would render in IE8 mode or Edge mode.

Comment: Yeah I tried the page viewer web part and it renders in IE8 unfortunately so I'm not sure what else I could do. Weirdly when i open up the .html file in a separate tab with tha t.html file residing in my sharepoint site, the default turns to IE5. I have no clue what might be causing that either,

Comment: That could happen if the page code has a missing or malformed [doctype declaration](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp), which should look like `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: if you're running SharePoint 2010,  make sure your on SP2 or later before you start using ID=Edge,  otherwise it will break ribbon functionality and cause issues with anything that does async callbacks. if you're on 2007,  then you cannot use IE=edge and continue to use SharePoint functionality.